# How to change the value of a column based on another column

Tags: sql

Lets say I have a database structured like so!

```
shoe_id | type        | price
_____________________________
1       | Adidas      | $50
2       | Nike        | $60
3       | Adidas      | $80
4       | Under Armor | $90
5       | Brooks      | $60
```

This is what a normal

```
SELECT shoe_id,
       type,
       price
FROM shoes;
```

would give me. I'm trying to censor the price of just Adidas shoes though. So I'm checking the type of the shoe, if it is adidas then I want to replace the price with a '-'. It would look like so.

```
shoe_id | type        | price
_____________________________
1       | Adidas      | -
2       | Nike        | 60
3       | Adidas      | -
4       | Under Armor | 90
5       | Brooks      | 60
```

Here is the code I have been trying.

```
SELECT shoe_id,
       type,
       CASE price
           WHEN type='adidas'
               THEN '-'
       END
FROM shoes
```

This doesn't work for all entries though and I'm not sure why. Are there any other ways to do this that would definitely work for every entry that the type is 'adidas'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea but the wrong syntax.  You need an `else` clause.  You can write:

```
SELECT shoe_id,type,
       (CASE WHEN type = 'Adidas' THEN '-'
             ELSE price
        END) as price
FROM shoes;
```

However, this might not work because you have a string and a number (presumably) coming out of the `case` statement.  You might want to format the price explicitly for the string, but the method depends on the database.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may have space or differnt case alphabets

So try this with upper and trim:

```
SELECT shoe_id,
       type,
       CASE upper(trim(type))
           WHEN 'ADIDAS'  THEN '-'
           else to_char(price,'$999.99')
       END
FROM shoes
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d90db/16)